# Call aliased column result of aggregate function JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, jooq

I'm currently trying to retrieve a single double value from this query in JOOQ Query Builder and PostgreSQL as the database, providing that DRINKS.PRICE is of type double and ORDER_DRINK.QTY is of type integer.

```
Record rec = create.select(DSL.sum(DRINKS.PRICE.multiply(ORDER_DRINK.QTY)).as("am_due")).from(ORDERS
                        .join(ORDER_DRINK
                            .join(DRINKS)
                            .on(DRINKS.DRINK_KEY.equal(ORDER_DRINK.DRINK_KEY)))
                        .on(ORDERS.ORDKEY.equal(ORDER_DRINK.ORDER_KEY)))
                        .where(ORDERS.TOKEN.eq(userToken))
                        .fetchOne();
```

As I've understood from the (brief) tutorial, once I retrieve the value from that aliased record, in the form:

```
double v = rec.getValue("am_due");
```

I should have the sum of all the prices multiplied by their quantities.
Still, I get a NullPointerException instead.

Any help would be very welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jOOQ usage is correct, but I suspect that your sum is simply `null` because:

- Your join doesn't return any records
- All of your multiplication operands are `null`

and since you're unboxing `Double` to `double`, you're getting that NullPointerException. You can solve this

#### ... using Java:

```java
Double v1 = rec.getValue("am_due");               // will return null
double v2 = rec.getValue("am_due", double.class); // will return 0.0
```

#### ... using jOOQ / SQL

```sql
Record rec = create.select(DSL.nvl(
  DSL.sum(
    DRINKS.PRICE.multiply(ORDER_DRINK.QTY)
  ), 0.0
).as("am_due"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to cast the getValue to double when I used some derived column with a non defined type previously.

Comment: @Urco: I see... it's actually not a cast, though. This approach applies type conversion as defined in [`org.jooq.tools.Convert`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/tools/Convert.html#convert-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-)